# ORDER BY function not working in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, sql-order-by

I'm using the ORDER BY function as per below to order a simple query by customer id (it was originally party age but that didn't seem to work so I changed it to see if it was the syntax or not).

```
SELECT   customer_id, customer_name, party_age
FROM     customer
ORDER BY customer_id
```

The report returns no errors, but when I go to view the report it is not ordered at all. I have tried this using numbers as well (ORDER BY x).

Anyone guide me in the right direction?

EDIT: Customer_id is VARCHAR2(3) with 10 sample data fields ranging from 001 to 010. I have tried converting to an int as suggested below but the results are still the same.

Comment: `ORDER BY function not working in Oracle` -- that's quite a statement, you know.

Comment: Can you provide example data?

Comment: And can you edit your question with results of this query: `select value from v$nls_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_SORT';`

Comment: please provide a sample. what's the datatype of customer_id? is it a varchar2 that really contains only numbers (if so `order by to_number(customer_id)`)

Comment: @Ben Results of that query is a Value of Binary returned.

Comment: ORDER BY utterly works in Oracle.  So the problem must lie in your data.  You have given some sample data but you still haven't demonstrated how the query returns that data.

Comment: Have you tested this in SQL*Plus? What "report" is giving the incorrect output?

Comment: Here is a SQL Fiddle.  The results are not surprising: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90b61/1   So it is up to you to justify your wild assertion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Order by` works in Oracle.  The problem must be that the results you are getting are different from what you expect.

A typical reason for this would be a number that is represented as a string.  This would order things as 1, 10, 100, 101, 102 . . .  which does not look correct, if you are expecting numeric ordering.

My guess is that the following would work:

```
 order by cast(customer_id as int)
```

Comment: I see your point but the ordering `1, 10, 100, 101, 102 . . .` does look correct :)